# How does a function call work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I started learning js recently and I have a question-
i.e in this code-

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button type="submit" id='1'>Click me!</button>
</body>
<script>
  function fun() {
    let x = Math.Random();
  }

  var x = document.getElementById('1');
  x.addEventListener("click", fun);
</script>

</html>
```

Do I get a different number every time I press the button? if not, why?
Don't I call the function every time I press the button, and thus I generate a different number?

Comment: That's not going to work. That's going to produce errors, and do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Why? won't it generate a different number when I press the button?

Comment: Think about what the function's called, and think about what you're passing to `addEventListener`. Also, you're never using that random number.

Comment: *"Do I get a different number every time I press the button?"* S.O. has snippets, I just edited your question adding one. Try it, and appreciate the beautiful error.

Comment: You never call `fun`.

Comment: I think he wanted to pass `fun` as callback not `function`

Comment: Yea I wanted to pass fun, mb tho....

Comment: I just fixed it, now, will it generate a different number every time I press the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.Random();` is change to `Math.random();`

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button type="submit" id='1'>Click me!</button>
  <p id="result"></p>
</body>
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById('1');
  x.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let x = Math.random();
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
 });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few problems with your code ,I have mentioned.

> ID  should begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). Though since HTML5,any non space character is allowed in Id.But its a good practice to have id something readable.

Moreover

> you should pass the callback as function expression ,you are passing
>   (function) which is a keyword

Third

> Its [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) not Math.Random()

```js
function fun() {
    let x = Math.random();
    console.log( x);
  }

  var x = document.getElementById('a1');
  x.addEventListener("click", fun); // you should pass the callback as function expression ,you are passing (function) which is a keyword
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button type="submit" id='a1'>Click me!</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: The restriction on ID is only for HTML4, in HTML5 [any one non-space character is allowed](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/dom.html#the-id-attribute). It is probably still a good idea to use a readable ID, though.